How to send a custom payload in botpress when user deletes conversation history?
I am sending a custom payload to the botpress cloud from webchat when "lifecycle.ready". But when the user deletes the conversation that custom info is not available.
I was expecting the lifecycle.ready to trigger in case of conversation history deletion as well

Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.
